# Hide splashscreen phonegap v3

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am trying to make sure that my splash screen does not show in `iOS phonegap v3`

I have tried the following as suggested in [their documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens):

Which includes installing the [splash plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1167)

I immediately call hide

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide()
```

**project layout**

```
¬ res
   ¬ icon
```

**config.xml**

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

Notice there is no splash folder. Yet, the splash screen will always show and also display the default phonegap splash screen rather than skipping it.

Worth mentioning I am building via https://build.phonegap.com

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the `deviceready` event is firing before you are calling `navigator.splashscreen.hide()`? Calling `.hide()` immediately after that event is fired should yield the result you are looking for.

Also, you can try replacing the splashscreen plugin altogether for cordova's new alternative:

`cordova.exec(null, null, “SplashScreen”, “hide”, [])`

The `cordova.exec` command hooks straight into the different devices native environments.

The parameters explained in more detail:

> ```
> function(winParam) {} - Success function callback. Assuming your exec call completes successfully, this function will be invoked (optionally with any parameters you pass back to it)
> function(error) {} - Error function callback. If the operation does not complete successfully, this function will be invoked (optionally with an error parameter)
> "service" - The service name to call into on the native side. This will be mapped to a native class.
> "action" - The action name to call into. This is picked up by the native class receiving the exec call, and, depending on the platform, essentially maps to a class's method.
> [/* arguments */] - Arguments to get passed into the native environment
> ```

Comment: Interesting... the exec functions are the direct hooks into the phones native functions. This looks nice!

Answer (score 0):

I think - stress think - that you can't do this. You could fake it perhaps by using a splash screen of a single color that matches the color of your app.